# How do I evaluate $\int \frac {x+4}{ 2x+6 } dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int  \frac {x+4}{ 2x+6 } dx$$

This is a problem from Khan Academy that I was reading about how to solve when I accidentally clicked next and lost the explanation. I was reading something about how there is a clever way to divide the function to make it easier to integrate. Can someone please explain this to me?

No actual solution, please. I want to get it by myself.

Comment: make the substitution u = 2x + 6

Comment: Split the numerator to be $x+3+1$ and then rewrite the fraction as $1/2+1/(2x+6)$.

Comment: You can do long division with polynomials. To get started, the number of times $2x+6$ goes into $x+4$ is $1/2$. (if we take the higher powers of $x$ to be the significant terms)

Comment: See http://encyclopedia-of-equation.webnode.jp/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

HINT: Notice $$\int\frac{x+4}{2x+6}dx$$  $$=\int\frac{x+4}{2(x+3)}dx$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x+4}{x+3}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(x+3)+1}{x+3}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(1+\frac{1}{x+3}\right)dx$$

Comment: So the answer is: $\frac { 1 }{ 2 } [x+ln|x+3|]+C$ ?

Comment: Yes, you  are absolutely right

Answer (score 6):

The change of variable $t=x+3$ simplifies the denominator and turns the integral in

$$\frac12\int\frac{t+1}tdt,$$ which should now be obvious.

Answer (score 4):

The way you have to think about it is like this. $$\int \frac{x+4}{2x+6}\ dx$$ then factor the denominator to get $2(x+3)$ then pull one half out the integral to get $$ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x+4}{x+3}\ dx$$. here is the cleverness rewrite $x+4$ as $x+3+1$ then simplify to get $$ \frac{1}{2}\int \left(1+ \frac{1}{x+3}\right) dx$$ 
Hope that helps.

Comment: So sorry i put the answer i was hoping she can work and get to it that is why i give the last step

Answer (score 2):

After seeing $ 2 x+ 6 $ in denominator and then the moment you see $x+4$ in numerator it should be doubled and halved as..

$$\int\frac{x+4}{2x+6}dx$$

$$=\frac12 \int\frac{2 x+8}{(2 x + 6 )}dx$$

$$=\frac{x}{2}+ \int\frac{dx}{2 x + 6}$$

$$=\frac{x}{2}+ \frac12 \int\frac{dx}{ x + 3},$$

it can be continued.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from, $$\int \frac{x+4}{2x+6}\ dx$$ $$=\int \frac{x}{2x+6}\ dx+\int \frac{4}{2x+6}\ dx$$ Making partial fractions, $$=\frac 12\int \frac{x+3-3}{x+3}\ dx+\int \frac{2}{x+3}\ dx$$
$$=\frac 12\int \ dx-\frac 32\int \frac{1}{x+3}\ dx+2\int \frac{1}{x+3}\ dx$$
$$=\frac x2+\frac 12\int \frac{1}{x+3}\ dx$$
$$=\frac x2+\frac 12\ln|x+3|+C$$
$$=\frac 12\left(x+\ln|x+3|\right)+C$$

Comment: I see that you have made a tremendous number of useless edits to this answer. Don't do that, especially if your only purpose is to try to bump your answer back to the front page.

Answer (score 1):

By chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus we have
$$
\int_{x} \frac{x+4}{2x+6} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x} \frac{2x+8}{2x+6} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x+3} \right) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\int_{x}\frac{D(x+3)}{x+3} + \text{some constant} \\= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\ln |x+3| + \text{some constant}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Singular behavior at $x = -3$:

$$\frac{x+4}{2x+6} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+3} +\mathcal{O}(1)$$

Singular behavior at infinity:

$$\frac{x+4}{2x+6} = \frac{1}{2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

The sum of all the singular parts of all the expansions around all singularities equals the rational function:

$$\frac{x+4}{2x+6} = \frac{1}{2}  +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+3}$$

This is true because the difference between the sum of all the singular parts of all the expansions around all singularities and the rational function has no singularities left including at infinity, which means that it is (up to removable singularities) a polynomial that tends to zero at infinity. This means that it is actually equal to zero everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{x+4}{2x+6}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac12\frac{2x+6+2}{2x+6}\ dx$$
$$=\frac12\int 1dx+\int\frac{2}{2x+6}\ dx$$
Let $2x+6=u\implies dx=du/2$
$$=\frac 12(x)+\int\frac{2(du/2)}{u}$$
$$=\frac x2+\int\frac{du}{u}$$
$$=\frac x2+\ln|u|+c$$
$$=\frac x2+\ln|2x+6|+c$$

Answer (score 0):

Any rational function may be integrated by the technique of *partial fractions*.

Very often $\ln$ or $\tan^{-1}$ appear in the solution.